# golang test context undefined XTestBackground

Tags: go

when i go to the directory go libirary src/context/ and do the test like that :
go test -v x_test.go  context.go context_test.go
it notice error :
go  undefined: XTestBackground
why ?

Comment: In Go you work on packages. Trying to execute tests from a single file (or running a single file) is **wrong**.

Comment: but i do "go test -v example_test.go"  is ok : 
```js
=== RUN   ExampleWithCancel
--- PASS: ExampleWithCancel (0.00s)
=== RUN   ExampleWithDeadline
--- PASS: ExampleWithDeadline (0.05s)
=== RUN   ExampleWithTimeout
--- PASS: ExampleWithTimeout (0.05s)
=== RUN   ExampleWithValue
--- PASS: ExampleWithValue (0.00s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  0.102s 
```